# Squares and areas

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

> In the dotted sheet below, the distances, both horizontally and vertically, between every two neighbouring points are equal.  Ann drew all possible squares by connecting four of the points.  How many different values can the area of the squares take.

I get only $4$.  if we consider distance between two dots are 1 cm, $1$.  1 sq cm. 2. 4 sq cm 3. 16 sq cm. 4. 2 (connecting two dots diagonally, $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} =2$).  But the answer is $D$.  I am unable to find the $5$th one.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Number the dots with $(0,0) $ at the lower left (so $(0,3)$  is the dot on the upper left, $(3,3)$ is the dot at the upper right, and $(3,0)$ is the dot on the lower right.  Then:  $(0,2),\;(2,3),\;(1,0),\;(3,1)$ make a square.

Answer (score 1):

Five areas are possible as follows:

[image]

It's also easy to see that the small square has 9 possible positions, the medium square has 4, the largest square has only 1, the diamond can be placed in 4 locations and the knight's-move tilted square only 2, for a total of 20 different squares.